# How it insert result of select statement into table of records (associative array)

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, record

I am working on HR scheme of oracle. I have table of records

```
   type emp_record is RECORD(emp_first_name employees.first_name%type,
                       emp_last_name  employees.last_name%type,
                       );



    type emp_record_table is table of emp_record
       index by pls_integer;
```

I want to insert into emp_record_table  results of the next select statement

```
   select first_name, last_name
   from employees
   where department_id=30;
```

can you explain me how to solve this problem? thank you.

Comment: Does it have to be an associative array?  The code would be simpler with a nested table.

Comment: it must be table of records, as I know this is only possible with associative arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (
  id         NUMBER(8,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR2(50),
  last_name  VARCHAR2(80)
);

CREATE PACKAGE test_pkg IS
  TYPE emp_record IS RECORD(
    emp_first_name employees.first_name%type,
    emp_last_name  employees.last_name%type
  );

  TYPE emp_record_table IS TABLE OF emp_record INDEX BY pls_integer;
END;
/

INSERT INTO employees( id, first_name, last_name )
  SELECT -1, 'a', 'aaa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT +3, 'b', 'bbb' FROM DUAL;
```

**PL/SQL Block**:

```sql
DECLARE
  x PLS_INTEGER;
  emps test_pkg.emp_record_table;
BEGIN
  -- Populate the associative array
  FOR row IN ( SELECT * FROM employees ) LOOP
    emps(row.id).emp_first_name := row.first_name;
    emps(row.id).emp_last_name  := row.last_name;
  END LOOP;

  -- Read the associative array
  x := emps.FIRST;
  WHILE x IS NOT NULL LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( x || ': ' || emps(x).emp_first_name || ' ' || emps(x).emp_last_name );
    x := emps.NEXT(x);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Output**:

> ```
> -1: a aaa
> 3: b bbb
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a38a46b6f223d1fd58dca27dbbf4e54)*

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach is to use bulk collect:

```
declare

  type emp_record is RECORD(emp_first_name employees.first_name%type,
                            emp_last_name  employees.last_name%type
                       );
  type emp_record_table is table of emp_record
       index by pls_integer;

  l_recs emp_record_table;

begin

  select first_name, last_name
  bulk collect into l_recs
  from employees
  where department_id=30;

  for idx in l_recs.first()..l_recs.last() loop
    dbms_output.put_line(l_recs(idx).emp_first_name ||' '|| l_recs(idx).emp_last_name);
  end loop;

end;       
/
```

Note that you don't really need an associative array to process records like this. You can ditch the `index by pls_integer` and things will still work just fine. The value of associative arrays is when we need to maintain an access path to specific rows. For instance, we might want to use the primary key of the `employees` table to index the array. This would create a **sparse array**, because the selected employee IDs are not guaranteed to form a contiguous sequence. Consequently the logic for wrangling the array is more verbose:

```
declare

  type emp_record is RECORD(emp_first_name employees.first_name%type,
                            emp_last_name  employees.last_name%type
                       );
  type emp_record_table is table of emp_record
       index by pls_integer;

  l_recs emp_record_table;
  idx pls_integer;

begin

  for r in (select emp_id, first_name, last_name
            from employees
            where department_id=30 )
  loop
      l_recs(r.emp_id).emp_first_name := r.first_name;
      l_recs(r.emp_id).emp_last_name  := r.last_name;
  end loop;

  idx := l_recs.first();
  while idx is not null loop
    dbms_output.put_line(l_recs(idx).emp_first_name ||' '|| l_recs(idx).emp_last_name);
    idx := l_recs.next(idx);
  end loop;

end;       
/
```

Here is [a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c6c395acdbce8644a4596d0d6aeb2452).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need associative array for that operation. Nested table will be perfect for that. Just declare your table type as following:

```
type emp_record_table is table of emp_record;
```

Firstly you have to declare table of your created type. Now you have only declared type or record and type of table of these records. You don't have yet your table. You can daclare it following way in the `DECLARE` section:

```
l_emp_table emp_record_table;
```

Then initialize it:

```
l_emp_table := emp_record_table();
```

Then you create cursor that will get data from your `SELECT` query. If you don't know how to do it, please read about cursor declaration, and fetching.

Next step will be: for each cursor row insert its data into table. You write simple loop that will do following steps:

1. Extend your declared table `l_emp_table.extend()`
2. Save data into table `l_emp_table(i).emp_first_name := FETCHED_ROW.first_name` and so on...